# How to divide large component class (1300+ lines) with non pure functions into multiple typescript files

Tags: angular, typescript, function, dependency-injection, extends

Our project contains 2-3 large stateful components where it's sometimes not the most fun to keep track of / keep clean and ordered all the functions defined. **Importing helpers (pure functions) from other files is not a problem**, but some of our larger functions act directly upon states and variables kept in said components class. We keep these states/objects in their respective components rather than services since they can get quite hefty and are not used application-wide, they're limited to their own instances.
How can we move these to separate files, so they would behave in a manner somewhat similar to:

*(functions simplified and shortened for illustration)*

**a.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import { B } from './a.b.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  templateUrl: './a.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./a.component.scss']
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private b: B) {}

    map: L.Map;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.map = new L.Map(...);
    }
    onUploaded(...) {
        this.b.loadAssets();
    }
}
```

**a.b.ts**

```
import { AComponent } from './a.component.ts';

export class B extends AComponent {
    loadAssets() {
        ...
        ...addTo.(this.map)
        this.map.flyTo(...)
    }
}
```

^ This throws us the following error: `angular Cannot access AComponent before initialization`

Angular's docs states that [the dependency in DI doesn't necessarily have to be a service and that it could be a function](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#dependency-injection-di), but I can't find any example of how to implement this and I'm unsure if that is what we would need.
Any help is greatly welcome!

Comment: You cannot include an instance of `B` as part of the constructor of `AComponent` since `B` extends A. That's your error. You want to your `AComponent` to extend `B` instead of the other way around. You do no need to include the extended class inside the constructor as it automatically inherits.

Comment: Makes sense! Working this way, is there anyway to have functions that reference a variable kept in the extended class (AComponent) from within the B class? And could this be compatible with extending multiple classes (e.g. using [ts mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html))?

Comment: Simple answer is "no." You would typically need to pass that variable into the function contained within B. But then what is the purpose of that variable? If every component that extends B will want an opportunity to call this function with this type of data, then why not put that variable in B and all of the components will have access to it, as well as B, itself.